# Where do I document first ascents?

Tags: climbing, united-states

I see a lot of people on social media posting their first ascents. These people are usually professional climbers climbing new super hard routes and as a result their first ascents blow up on social media. But what if, hypothetically, I find an untouched boulder at make the first ascent of a V0 boulder. Where would I document this? If there isn't some central database, how will people know if they actually made the first ascent of something?

A quick google search for first ascent documentation turned up fruitless.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the United States, a lot of climbers use [www.mountainproject.com](http://www.mountainproject.com) (MP) to document outdoor climbs and first ascents. If you discover a new boulder problem or bolt a new route, you could submit it here and enter any first ascent (FA) information. See example below:

[image: screenshot of mountainproject.com]

Some climbs had first ascents way before MP came about, so there are discussion boards for each climb where people exchange information (either first-hand or second-hand) about who may have been the first person to climb or bolt a route. This information can then be added to this particular climbing route.

Comment: This is country dependant. In UK most people log it on http://www.ukclimbing.com/logbook/